# Function which graph looks looks like the plane

Tags: functions

> Does there exist a function which is surjective from $[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$ such that $a\ne b$?

Of course such a function would have a graph which looks like the plane.

I can see that it is, of course, not continuous.

Do you have any examples of such functions? Do they exist?

Comment: $\tan ( \frac{b - a }{\pi} x + a )$ will suite that, after you choose some falues for $f(a)$ and $f(b)$

Comment: @PenasRaul Right of course, I actually meant a function which does not depend on $a$ and $b$

Comment: I don't have my copy of Gelbaum and Olmsted handy, but I bet this question is answered in that book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if we're allowed to rely on the axiom of choice.

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$. Since each equivalence class is countable, the set of equivalence classes (a.k.a. the quotient $\mathbb{R}/{\sim}$) has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, hence there is a bijection $g\colon\mathbb{R}/{\sim}\to\mathbb{R}$. Now let $f(x)=g([x])$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$.

Comment: So without the axiom of choice, the function does not exist?

Comment: That is too strong a statement. But I don't know how to construct one.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the Axiom of Choice - the non-linear solutions to Cauchy's functional equation may be an interesting candidate.

Some of the interesting properties which such solutions possess are :

- They are discontinuous everywhere (nowhere continuous)
- They are unbounded on any segment, no matter how small (nowhere locally bounded)
- From the above it also follows that it is nowhere locally monotone.
- They are dense in $\mathbb{R^2}$

You can read up on Cauchy's Functional Equation on Wikipedia :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Here's an article from a blogger on the non-linear solutions to CFE :

http://www.cofault.com/2010/01/hunt-for-addictive-monster.html

The above article also gives a nice construction of such a "monster".